# postgresql array / composite output

Tags: postgresql, escaping

In my app, I am using postgresql to return composite type values like this:

```
select row('a','b','c','d');
```

This query returns:

> (a,b,c,d)

I am using more complex types, which contains arrays of other composite types etc. In my DB layer, I parse returned value and "unpack" arrays and other composites from it.

The problem?

```
select row(array[1,2,3,4]);
```

and

```
select row('{1,2,3,4}');
```

gives exactly same output:

> ("{1,2,3,4}")

How can I distinguish when this `'{1,2,3,4}'` is meant as regular string (possibly supplied by user) and when it is meant as array?

Should not be there something like escape sequence for `{` and `}` in composite field value?

P.S. I cannot use something like `select * from row[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way to determine column type is to query result set metadata.

I can't tell you how because you didn't specify your framework/language. In general you need to extend some result set class and resolve this disambiguity there.

Comment: I knew about possiblity of queriing metadata of result set, but you (together with Craig Ringer) helped me to look on a problem from different view. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using anonymous records, this will be challenging. Observe:

```
SELECT pg_typeof( row('{1,2,3,4}') ), pg_typeof( row(array[1,2,3,4]) );
```

If possible use named types with `CREATE TYPE` instead of anonymous records (`ROW()` constructors) . Then you can examine the rowtypes.

```
CREATE TYPE r1 AS (col1 text);
CREATE TYPE r2 AS (col1 integer[]);

SELECT pg_typeof( row('{1,2,3,4}')::r1 ), pg_typeof( row(array[1,2,3,4])::r2 );
```

There may be more detail in the protocol-level result set metadata, as Ondrej suggests, offering ways to do this without having to use record types.

Comment: your SQL gives exact same result for both: `record`. What gives?

Comment: @mvp Exactly - you can't just use `pg_typeof` to determine the internal type of a `record`. I'll amend my answer to make that clearer.